# Regex to extract a named group of words till newline?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out what regex will extract these named groups, each on a separate line. Tried different combinations, but am stuck. For instance, I am unable to extract localityDefault but get:

> hasData false
>
> patternMatch7()  null

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String patternOfData = ".*?orgUnit1Default=(?<orgUnit1Default>\\S+)\\s+" +
            "orgUnit2Default=(?<orgUnit2Default>\\S+)\\s+" +
            "organizationDefault=(?<organizationDefault>\\S+)\\s+" +
            "localityDefault=(?<localityDefault>\\S+)\\s+?" +
            "stateDefault=(?<stateDefault>\\S+)\\s+?" +
            "countryDefault=(?<countryDefault>\\S+)\\s+";
    String receivedDataString = "orgUnit1Default=window washers \n"
            + "orgUnit2Default=All Cleaners \n"
            + "organizationDefault=Cleaning Dept \n"
            + "localityDefault=Small Town Here\n"
            + "stateDefault=Washington\n" 
            + "countryDefault=US";
    String toExtractName = "organizationDefault";

    System.out.println("patternMatch7()  "
            + patternMatch7(patternOfData, receivedDataString,
                    toExtractName));
}

static String patternMatch7(String patternOfData,
        String receivedDataString, String toExtractName) throws IOException {
    Pattern dataExtractionPattern;
    dataExtractionPattern = Pattern.compile(patternOfData, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = dataExtractionPattern.matcher(receivedDataString);
    boolean hasData = false;
    String dataValue = null;
    if (matcher.find()) {
        hasData = true;
        dataValue = matcher.group(toExtractName);
    }
    System.out.println("hasData " + hasData);

    return dataValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your data look exactly but could you try this regex?

```
String patternOfData = ".*?orgUnit1Default=(?<orgUnit1Default>.+)\\s*\n" +
        "orgUnit2Default=(?<orgUnit2Default>.+)\\s*\n" +
        "organizationDefault=(?<organizationDefault>.+)\\s*\n" +
        "localityDefault=(?<localityDefault>.+)\\s*\n" +
        "stateDefault=(?<stateDefault>.+)\\s*\n" +
        "countryDefault=(?<countryDefault>.+)";
```

Comment: @likejiujitsu If this is real and entire data you will have to parse then my regex should work for you. Now result of your program will be `hasData true patternMatch7()  Cleaning Dept `

Comment: Thank you, but for countryDefault it fails. It is eating up the 'S' `hasData true
patternMatch7()  U`

Answer (score 0):

your pattern assumes there is whitespace before newline, but locality has no whitespace before newline -- use * instead of +

```
+ "organizationDefault=Cleaning Dept \n"
                                    ^     space character

+ "localityDefault=Small Town Here\n"
                                  ^       no space character...
```

Why wouldn't you use LDAPs search instead??